# Copy sqlite database from device to PC

Tags: android, database, sqlite, transfer

I have an android program that stores its information in a sqlite database. Will it be straighforward to copy that db file to a pc once the device is plugged via USB or should a special functionality be written in the program itself to dump the db contents to a file under the /sdcard directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Pulling SQlite database android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997976/android-pulling-sqlite-database-android-device)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the adb pull command to read a file from the teathered device to your desktop, e.g. `adb pull /data/data/com.foo.bar/databases/MyDatabase`

Comment: Wow, in my case it IS signed.

Comment: Yes, its not really clear if the question is about a one off development task, or about an actual product feature.

Comment: You're right ... It's about a product feature that if not present, a workaround can be implemented via coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bat file and run it , it will create a folder name clonedb and pull all database to this

```
adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/clonedb
adb shell run-as <app package> cp -r /data/data/<app package>/databases/. /sdcard/clonedb
adb pull /sdcard/clonedb ./
```