# Debugging sqlite database on the device

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I am presently working on an WiFi application for Android. I am having trouble trying to access the database on the device. Debugging in the emulator doesn't work for me, because there is no WiFi support in the emulator. I tried pulling the database file out of the device by using

```
adb pull data/data/package-name/databases/database-name
```

But I get the error "Permission denied.". 
In this answer [Android: Where are database files stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105219/android-where-are-database-files-stored/1106563#1106563), Commonsware has suggested to pull database file by running in debug mode. But it doesn't work too. Any help on how to debug the database without rooting the device would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I'll repeat myself from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433520/648313):

> Starting from API level 8 (Android 2.2), if you build the application as debuggable, you can use the shell `run-as` command to run a command or executable as a specific user/application or just switch to the `UID` of your application so you can access its `data` directory.

#### Copy files to external storage on the device

So if you wish to pull your application database from the device you can launch a debug build of the application from Android Studio, connect with `adb shell` and run the following command:

```
run-as com.your.package sh -c "cat ~/databases/db-file.db" > /sdcard/db-file.db
```

or you can use a shorter version which uses relative paths and by skipping the reference to the home directory `~` can omit the `sh -c` part too:

```
run-as com.your.package cat databases/db-file.db > /sdcard/db-file.db
```

This will copy your `db-file.db` to the root of your SD card / external storage. Now you can easily get it from there by using file manager, `adb pull` or whatever else you like. Note that with this approach, there is NO need for your app to have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, as the copying is done by the `shell` user who can always write to the external storage.

#### Copy files directly to the computer

You can also copy a database directly to your computer with the following command:

```
adb shell 'run-as com.your.package cat databases/db-file.db' > db-file.db
```

The `adb shell` command above will not work correctly on Windows host because of the `CR/LF` symbols conversion, unless you run it from a `bash` shell or use the undocumented `adb exec-out` command instead (some comments mention they still cannot get it to work correctly on a Windows machine, so your mileage may vary):

```
adb exec-out 'run-as com.your.package cat databases/db-file.db' > db-file.db
```

#### Write files back to the device

If you modified the file on your computer and wish to write the modifications back to the device use the following command:

```
adb exec-in 'run-as com.your.package tee databases/db-file.db' < db-file.db
```

or if you prefer an `adb shell` version over undocumented `exec-in`, use the following (but read the concern about the Windows `CR/LF` conversion above):

```
adb shell 'run-as com.your.package tee databases/db-file.db' < db-file.db >/dev/null
```

###### Status update

All the commands above are still working as of July, 2023

Comment: @Idolon, I tried this answer and was able to download the database but now when I try and open it with sqlite it give me the error "Error: file is encrypted or is not a database".  Any ideas how I can fix it and access through sqlite?

Comment: @MikeIsrael Just in case, you don't use SQLCipher in your app do you? If not, then to roughly check whether the database was downloaded correctly open the DB file in a viewer (preferably a hex-viewer) and check whether it starts with `SQLite format 3` string.  Also make sure you have a correct `sqlite` version (i.e. you're not trying to open sqlite3 database with sqlite2 executable). And you may also try other SQLite clients (for example [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/)). Hope it helps.

Comment: You made my day @Idolon! A little improvement to your answer: android:debuggable="true" is not needed, it's the default AFAIK in the manifest. I've just typed run-as and cat in my adb shell and worked perfectly, without android:debuggable in the manifest

Comment: @Jose_GD Yes, you're right - [android:debuggable is set automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5701672/648313) by the Eclipse ADT plugin.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the one liner. It works fine if I run the command in a shell but if I put in the one liner I get:
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: package <my package> is unknown... anyone know why. I installed via studio by pressing the debug button.

Comment: @schwiz There is a known bug in Android 4.3: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373. And few workarounds, for example making [run-as set-uid root](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373#c41), `/data/…` folders permission changes may also be required: [post #60](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373#c60)

Comment: On Android Lollipop i'm getting `permission denied`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I get that on Lollipop too. Managed to get a semi-accessible database by catting it through the adb link and writing to a file on the local computer. Like `adb shell 'run-as myapp cat /data/data/myapp/databases/dbname.db' > ~/dbname.db` Something's kind of wrong with that, but I'm not sure what yet.

Comment: @Mason thanks but you said you managed to get it and then you are saying something's wrong. I'm confused :?

Comment: I pulled a database with two tables and a dozen or so rows in each, and did full select queries on each table. One worked fine, the other reported a data error in the file. My best guess right now is an encoding mismatch between the Android and local shell.

Comment: @Mason Is your phone rooted? I'm still getting `permission-denied` & `read-only-filesystem` error :(

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Nope, if it was rooted, I could just do a pull of the file I wanted. Try running the commands from a adb shell, and make sure the run-as command works, and that your app is built in debug mode.

Comment: @Mason i already did run in adb shell and the command is working. The apk is debugged with eclipse using debug.keystore. Is your device 5.0.1?

Comment: I am also having the same problem but not on lollipop but on Android 4.0.4. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but keep in mind you are doing your 'cat' in context of your app.  Make sure your has WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: If for some reason you are like me getting an error stating `Device not found`: Simply replace the `-d` with `-s <device-id>`. `<device-id>` needs to be replaced by the device id given in the left column in the output of `adb devices`. This happened to me while using a virtual genymotion device.

Comment: mine needed to have quotes: `adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackage cat /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/dbname.sqlite > /sdcard/dbname.sqlite"`

Comment: `adb shell 'run-as com.yourpackage sh -c "cat ~/databases/db-file"' > db-file.sqlite` is not going to work regardless of the host OS. see my explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587203/1778421

Comment: also why do you keep insisting on using the unnecessary `sh -c "cat file"` construct? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472135/1778421 is much cleaner.

Comment: By running bash on windows cmd, the linux and mac command at the bottom of this answer can also be used.

Answer (score 23):

I use this shell script on my MAC, that copies database directly to my home folder. Easy one click solution, just change package name (com.example.app) and database name (database.sqlite)

Simple Script

```
#!/bin/bash
adb -d shell 'run-as com.example.app cat /data/data/com.example.app/databases/database.sqlite > /sdcard/database.sqlite'
adb pull /sdcard/database.sqlite ~/
```

Script which accepts arguments [package_name] [database]

```
#!/bin/bash

REQUIRED_ARGS=2
ADB_PATH=/Users/Tadas/Library/sdk/platform-tools/adb
PULL_DIR="~/"

if [ $# -ne $REQUIRED_ARGS ]
    then
        echo ""
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "android_db_move.sh [package_name] [db_name]"
        echo "eg. android_db_move.sh lt.appcamp.impuls impuls.db"
        echo ""
    exit 1
fi;


echo""

cmd1="$ADB_PATH -d shell 'run-as $1 cat /data/data/$1/databases/$2 > /sdcard/$2' "
cmd2="$ADB_PATH pull /sdcard/$2 $PULL_DIR"

echo $cmd1
eval $cmd1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo ".........OK"
fi;

echo $cmd2
eval $cmd2

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo ".........OK"
fi;

exit 0
```

Comment: The first command was creating a zero-byte copy of the database, so I made some adjustments in your script:
https://gist.github.com/romulof/6af8a8919660f395f975

Answer (score 15):

The best way to view and manage you android app database is to use this library https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android

With this library you can manage your app SQLite database from you app itself.
you can view the tables in your app database , update ,delete, insert rows to your tables .Everything from your app.

Its a single java activity file ,just add the java file to your source folder.When the development is done remove the java file from your src folder thats it .

It helped me a lot .Hope it helps you too .

You can view the 1 minute demo here : http://youtu.be/P5vpaGoBlBY

Answer (score 13):

Although, it's an old question I think it's still relevant and deserves a current state answer. There are tools available, which allow you to inspect databases directly (without the need to pull them from the device or emulator).

The tool, I most recently discovered (and favor most) is [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database).

You only need to add this dependency:

```
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'
```

No further code is required.
After you started your app, open logcat and filter for "DebugDB" and you will find a message saying

```
D/DebugDB: Open http://192.168.178.XXX:8080 in your browser
```

It works with every browser and you can inspect your database tables and shared preferences.

[image]

It also works with the default and the Genymotion emulators.

---

The tool I used before is [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/).

Downside: You need to add a bit of code and you are bound to the Chrome browser.

Advantage: You have the option to also inspect network traffic.

Answer (score 6):

In the new **Android Studio 4.1** there is the new [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector).

[image: https://i.ibb.co/9tNM1xg/database-Inspector.gif]

You can select the following options from the menu bar `View > Tool Windows > Database Inspector` to open it (`App Inspector` in Android Studio 4.2). More detailed instructions can be found in [this blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-inspector-9e91aa265316) and  in [Exploring the Database Inspector in Android Studio](https://medium.com/better-programming/exploring-the-database-inspector-in-android-studio-de0026024895) medium article.

Another way is to use [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) for this. You add the dependency and then can use the Chrome DevTools ( chrome://inspect ) to check the database when the device is plugged in.

Answer (score 5):

In my application I export the database to the SD card.  Once the database is on the SD card it can be accessed by plugging the device into your computer.

Look at this post: [Making a database backup to SDCard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814213/making-a-database-backup-to-sdcard-on-android)

Answer (score 5):

If you get

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

try

```
adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackage cat /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/dbname.sqlite > /sdcard/dbname.sqlite"
```

Note the double quote!

Comment: I tried this and it creates the file but it's 0kb

Answer (score 3):

I simply did:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ run-as myapp.package.name sh
shell@android:/data/data/myapp.package.name $
```

Then I can debug an sqlite database or whatever I wanna do from shell with the right permissions.

Answer (score 3):

**Android Studio 4.1** Added a new feature to view/ edit Android SQLite databases.

[image]

### How to open Database Inspector

To open the Database Inspector in Android Studio, you need to select `View > Tool Windows > Database Inspector` from the menu bar.

Also you need to run the app to a device running API level 26 or higher.

Using this tool you can

- Query your databases
- Modify and debug your database

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a way if an apk is debuggable to use a program called run-as from the (non-root) adb shell to copy an application's private file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is step by step instructions - mostly taken from a combination of the other answers. This works with devices that are not unlocked.

1. Connect your device and launch the application in debug mode.
2. Copy the database file from your application folder to your sd card: execute:

   ./adb -d shell 'run-as com.yourpackge.name cat /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/filename.sqlite > /sdcard/filename.sqlite'
3. Pull the database files to your machine: execute:

   ./adb pull /sdcard/ execute: ./adb
4. Install Firefox SQLLite Manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
5. Open Firefox SQLLite Manager and open your database file from step 3 above.
6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running adb as root, or be using it on a rooted phone.

To run adb as root, use `adb root`

See also: [Why do I get access denied to data folder when using adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043322/why-do-i-get-access-denied-to-data-folder-when-using-adb)

Comment: I had tried this. But it gives me "adb cannot run as root in production builds"

Comment: You'll need to run it in Debug mode.

Comment: See this: http://www.mydroidworld.com/forums/android-hacks/5508-adb-help-needed-adbd-cannot-run-root-production-builds.html
If you're running it on a phone and not an emulator, you'll have to root it.

Comment: I ran the application in debug mode and tried the above steps as well. It doesn't work.

Comment: This only works for the emulator or a rooted device.

Comment: If you get the error "run-as: unknown package" double check the applicationId in your build.gradle file.  That is the value that determines the "package" ID - not the actual package name in the code.

Answer (score 1):

None of the `run-as`-and-cat-to-sdcard solutions worked for me on Android 4.4.2. I'm not sure, but I suspect it may be due to the `run-as` tool not correctly handling the new `sdcard_r` and `sdcard_rw` permissions.

I first had to copy the database file to `/files` in my application's private internal storage:

```
shell@hammerhead:/ $ run-as com.example.myapp   
shell@hammerhead:/data/data/com.example.myapp $ cp databases/mydb files/mydb
```

Then I copied to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files` in Javaland (this requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission):

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...

         if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
             final FileInputStream input;
             try {
                 input = openFileInput("mydb");

                 File output = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "mydb");

                 copy(input, output);
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }

     public void copy(FileInputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

         // Transfer bytes from in to out
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int len;
         while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
             out.write(buf, 0, len);
         }
         in.close();
         out.close();
     }

     public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
         String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
         return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
     }
 }
```

Finally, I copied the file to my laptop:

```
$ adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/mydb
```

Comment: There's a simpler solution. If you chmod 777 your sqlite file, then exit run-as, it'll let you copy it over to /sdcard as the regular usre.

Answer (score 1):

#### My Device was not having sdcard

so the first solution did not work for me.

If you are having similar issue try like this:

```
  adb shell "run-as package chmod 777 /data/data/package/databases/yourdb.sqlite";
  adb pull /data/data/package/databases/yourdb.sqlite
```

Comment: `/sdcard` isn't necessarily an SD card. On my phone it points to internal storage when no physical SD card is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this app: SQLiteWeb (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.cm.sqliteweb). It provides remote access to your database without pulling it out.

In paid version, it has root access for private database (/data/data/package-name...) or implement a Content Provider to connect using SQLiteWeb (Instructions inside app)

But if want to stay with the free version, you may create your database in external storage:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

On OSX,using @Tadas answer with automator and sqllitebrowser(https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser):

1. open Automator and create new workflow.
2. add "Run Shell Script" action.
3. Paste this :

   source ~/.bash_profile
   adb shell 'run-as  cat /data/data/your_app_uid/databases/db.name > /tmp/db.name'
   adb pull /tmp/db.name ~/
   open -a sqlitebrowser ~/db.name
4. click run to refresh the database on sqlitebrowser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up a terminal
2. `cd <ANDROID_SDK_PATH>` (for me on Windows `cd C:\Users\Willi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`)
3. `cd platform-tools`
4. `adb shell` (this works only if only one emulator is running)
5. `cd data/data`
6. `su` (gain super user privileges)
7. `cd <PACKAGE_NAME>/databases`
8. `sqlite3 <DB_NAME>`
9. issue SQL statements (**important:** terminate them with `;`, otherwise the statement is not issued and it breaks to a new line instead.)

Note: Use `ls` (Linux) or `dir` (Windows) if you need to list directory contents.