# Accessing existing SQLite database using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created an android app in java using eclipse which creates a SQLite database and lets the user add data to it.

I would like to know how to access an already existing SQLite database (say, in our web server) to view and add data to it ?
I Googled it and didn't get any clear picture. Do I need to install JDBC driver for doing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: SQLiteadmin could be what you need (it's a traditional app, and not a web application though): http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

Comment: And how use it to access database in phone memory?

Comment: [SQLite is Serverless](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html). There are webservices and things like that building upon SQLite but if you want a database with remote access you're probably better off using something else.

Comment: @zapl I think questioner need in ease way access database file in phone memory ant manipulate it.

Comment: @neworld possible, questioneer is not very clear about how device internal db and db on webserver should interact, or if at all. If it's about getting the file from the device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device

Comment: @zapl this method is very hard. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not a client/server database.
That said, the [SQLite wiki](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork) mentions some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a remote database from your app, you will need an interface (like a web service) that will take requests from your app and actually do the database manipulation. If you just want to access a local database from your computer, there are several utilities for it to do it graphically or you can use sqlite3 to do it from the command line. If you want to access the database through your browser, I think you need a web service for that too.

Comment: I read something about the JDBC driver and I wanted to know if I have to use that to form a connection between the SQLite database in our web server and java code in eclipse.