# How to import the external sqlite data base to program when mobile debug connect USB?

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging

I can pull the database in `data/data/com..../ ...` catalogue directly in emulator. But when I connect the mobile it can not.

I do not want to use file IO to write in this catalogue.

Is there some method pull directly? Or use some cmd command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you will find this usefull:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device

Answer (score 1):

put your sqlite data base file into assets folder and copy this file into local memory......

try this link

http://androidrocksonmobility.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-get-sqlite-path-in-asset-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

if your device is rooted. you should copy it to the SDCARD firstly.
using:

1. cat /data/data/com.***/database/*.db > /sdcard/dest.db
2. pull it out.

if your device is not rooted. if you really want to copy it. copy it in your program.