# How to test whether database is encrypted after adding SQLCipher?

Tags: android, testing, sqlcipher

After adding the SQLCipher libs,
and adding calls to

```
SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
```

How do I confirm that my app database is encrypted?

I tried accessing the .db via adb.
adb shell says permissions denied or error when trying to access the db file for inspection.

Comment: Use a rooted phone or an emulator to adb shell into and examine the sql db file that way.

Comment: Yeah, decided to root a device to examine the db file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried accessing the .db via adb. adb shell says permissions denied or error when trying to access the db file for inspection.

Use an emulator and DDMS or `adb pull` (see [this blog post](http://www.andreybutov.com/2013/03/14/a-quick-way-to-view-your-android-apps-sqlite-database-during-development/) for a shell script for the latter).

Or [use `adb shell run-as` on a production device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8434477/115145), assuming the device isn't seriously old.

However, you still will be unable to open the database, unless you are using a SQLCipher-enabled copy of `sqlite3` or some other client.