# Trying to debug sqlite DB from device, but permission denied when copying db to SD

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I'm following the instructions here:
[Debugging sqlite database on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device).

My problem arises when trying to copy the file to sdcard. If I run the full command, it doesn't give me any message, and the file isn't there when i go there through My Computer. If I break the commands down and run them one by one, when I do cat, I get the following:

> sh: can't create /sdcard/Database.db: Permission denied

I also have both permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18472135/1778421

Comment: @AlexP. want to move that to an answer to accept it? Not sure how I didn't stumble over that when looking for a solution.