# When creating an SQLite database for an Android phone, if I execute the necessary statements to create it, I should be able to see it

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I use the Android Device Manager to see the database or does the database exists only in memory? Below is my code to create the database.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlitedb;
sqlitedb = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
sqlitedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXITS MyTable("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY 
        KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(150));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View contents of database file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: I have looked at that very link. It does not work when I try to see the database. I click on my program link and then click on the data link. Nothing is in the directory. Has anyone tried this lately? Is there some sort of pre-configuration I need to perform to make this work?

Comment: then try this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928849/debugging-sqlite-database-on-the-device

Comment: This line: `sqlitedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXITS MyTable("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY 
        KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(150));` won't even compile

Comment: You may find the following of interest/use [Are there any methods that assist with resolving common SQLite issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues/46642271#46642271)

Comment: Sorry!!! The line should read sqlitedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXITS MyTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY 
        KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(150));");

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question the answer is yes you can.

from the android documents....

> From a remote shell to your device or from your host machine, you can
>   use the sqlite3 command-line program to manage SQLite databases
>   created by Android applications. The sqlite3 tool includes many useful
>   commands, such as .dump to print out the contents of a table and
>   .schema to print the SQL CREATE statement for an existing table. The
>   tool also gives you the ability to execute SQLite commands on the fly.

read more in here : 
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html