# Sqlite error: unable to open database "/data/data/PackageName/databases/SampleDB.db": unable to open database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting an error while connecting to Sqlite DB in android through command prompt.

Here are the steps I have followed:

- I have created Sqlite DB through java program in android. Created table and inserted data into it. Executed query to get data. Everything fine!!!!
- Tried to conned to DB though ***Command Prompt*** :

  ```
  D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools> adb shell

  adb shell

  root@generic:/ #  sqlite3 /data/data/package-name/databases/SampleDB.db

  sqlite3 /data/data/package-name/databases/Samp
  ant.encryptdata/databases/Samp                                                <leDB.db

  SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
  Enter ".help" for instructions
  Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

  sqlite> .tables
  .tables

  SQL Error: unable to open database "/data/data/com.congnizant.encryptdata/databases/SampleDB.db": unable to open database file
  1|root@generic:/ #
  ```

Actually i want to post screenshot for better understanding but i dont know why its not working(may be becuase of my office firewall).

```
Permision for SampleDB is '-rw-rw----';
```

So where am I doing worng?

**Note:** The database is present having one sample table and i can read write data into that table.

Comment: Do you have read permission for the file?? I am not sure but i guess you need root access for the same

Comment: Check the permission @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997976/android-pulling-sqlite-database-android-device answer by Lam Vin

Comment: @Raghunandan you can check the edit for file permission. I have gone through the post suggested by you getting error cited in first comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like my very same problem not long ago.

You may test something first. Once you're connected to the device with `adb shell`, try `ls data/data/<application_namespace_id>/databases/`. If it returns `opendir failed, Permission denied`, it should be the same problem I had: ADB permissions issue. And here's what solved my problem:

1. Go to 'Developer Options' in your device (If you it isn't visible go to 'Settings' > 'About phone' in your phone and tap 'Build number' several times until 'Developer Options' are enabled)
2. Then make sure 'Developer Options' are  actually enabled
3. On 'Developer Options' screen, enable 'Android debugging' to allow Android debug
4. On same screen, make sure ADB has permissions in 'Root access'

Now, try again your commands. But once you enter `adb shell` also enter `su` to enable Super User mode. You should see a `#` confirming your shell on Super User mode.

If you have only one device connected, it should work now. Otherwise, you should also confirm if you're connected to the right device by listing your devices first running `adb devices` and connecting to right one `adb -d <device_reference_here> shell`.

You'll probably also need your phone rooted to do any of this.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
I had similar below issue on android emulator:

**Issue:**
1)generic_x86:/ $     sqlite3 EmployeeRecords
SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

2)sqlite> select * from employee
   ...> ;

Error: unable to open database "EmployeeRecords": unable to open database file

**Solution**

1)C:\Users\Hpo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
2)generic_x86:/ $ exit
3)C:\Users\Hpo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb root
4)C:\Users\Hpo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb root restarting adbd as root
5)C:\Users\Hpo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
6)generic_x86:/ # cd /data/data/com.example.hpo.crud_myapplication/databases/
7)generic_x86:/data/data/com.example.hpo.crud_myapplication/databases # 
sqlite3  EmployeeRecords
8)sqlite> select * from employee
   ...> ;
1|sachin|15000

and it's working.
```