# How to open SQLite database on DB Browser for SQLite(No emulator)

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have been looking for hours now how to see my database using the program `DB Browser for SQLite` (http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

I downloaded the software and i can't find any file on my computer that can be opened with this software.

So what kind of file android `SQLiteOpenHelper` class generates? And how can i open it using the software mentioned(Or any other way i can see my database?).

I'm not using emulator. I run my app on an actual device.

**EDIT**
So i guess i need to do this `adb pull data/data/package-name/databases/database-name` and i really dont know how to do it.

Comment: Why not using [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin&hl=en)

Comment: @Tony Never heard of it. Just installed it.I will check it out.

Comment: Alright, make sure you root your device

Comment: @Tony My device is not rooted so i cant open it with SQLite Debugger.It says i can only open it using sd card.

Comment: Try root your device and see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the sqlite database in device android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33722841/1841194

Comment: @Mohit I have already checked that post(Even voted) but foound no solution for my problem.

Comment: @Tony If i dont want to hack my device? :)

Comment: @God I would suggest you to root your device. The app I suggested to you quiet easy to use

Comment: @Mohit So in that thread he says to run this command `adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name ls /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/"`. I dont know how to run it.

Comment: write the command in your (windows) cmd / (Linux) Terminal

Comment: @Mohit In cmd its not recognizes the `adb` command.

Comment: you have to set path for that..check [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38321/what-do-i-type-in-path-variable-for-adb-server-to-start-from-cmd) and [this](http://jaxov.com/2010/10/set-up-adb-on-windows-7-vista-xp-for-android-phones/)

Comment: @Mohit I cant manage to set the path. I tried `C:\Users\volca_000\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`. Is that the path i need to enter?

Comment: In my case (I'm using Eclipse, on Windows), it's `C:\Program Files\Adt-Bundle\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: @Mohit No. When i run the `adb -d shell "run-as com.yourpackge.name ls /data/data/com.yourpackge.name/databases/"` command i get `/data/data/com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial/database/: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

In my development i encountered same issue. Your database gets saved in "*/data/data/yourapp/database.db*".

This is not reachable by default. You have to root your device to view this location. This is something i didn't do. Instead i saved my database in another location that is reachable by default.

```
public static final String database_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "folder name";
```

Then i went in the Android Device Monitor and looked at that location to find my database.

Once i found it i used SQLiteStudio to view my database and look if everything is in order.

See http://sqlitestudio.pl for more information

Does that help you out ?

### Update 1

You can put your database where you like, any folder you haver permission on. Then you will have to add the path to your constructor of your helper.

```
public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, 8);
    this.myContext= context;
}
```

How do you get your database? You copy it or you create it programmatically?

Comment: Where did you exactly wrote that path line of code?

Comment: In your helper class for your database. My predefined db is in the assets folder, where i copy it locally into the device at the location i want. Be sure to set in the manifest, write external storage...See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html for reference

Comment: Thanks. i will look after that tomorrow.

Comment: The `"folder name" is any folder i choose? Like to open a new folder an call it db and store it there?

Comment: I do it programmatically. i Created a folder called`UsersDb` and then i wrote in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class `public static final String DATABASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "UsersDb";` and now i only need to add the path to the constructor like you wrote?

Comment: You should rerun your project. Set your DB version higher so the onupdate db get executed. Or just delete and reïnstall your app. Can you see your db now ?
Between your path and dbname , i would put a package name like "be.name.com".

Comment: Man i'm, sorry but i really dont understand. I think ill pass for now. Thanks for the help though.