# How can I get information about the column caused foreign key constraint in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints

I want to know if it is possible to get information about `SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint` exception.

I need to know which **column** caused a violation of foreign key constraint.

Is there any way to get these information from the exception?

Also it can be good if I could get the name of that Constraint.

Comment: Is it possible to infer the missing constraint in your catch clause ? A data dump might help on catch.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can find the answer in the following qestion:

[Possible to get specific error details from Android SQLiteConstraintException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575425/possible-to-get-specific-error-details-from-android-sqliteconstraintexception)

Look at solution 2 posted by antoino.

Comment: There is no valuable data in his solution

Comment: The solution provides everything you need to get more information about the exact error. You can print the Stack Trace dump, which should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

> No direct way to find column name that violate the foreign key
>   constraint from SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint
>   exception.

But you can find operation(delete, insert, create etc) name that raise  SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint exception.In following log

```
 04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:           
    foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at it.jackpot21.personalmoney.DbAdapter.SQLdelete(DbAdapter.java:89)
    04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at it.jackpot21.personalmoney.PersoneActivity$5.onClick(PersoneActivity.java:215)
```

In the above log

> 04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)

this tells us delete operation raise exception. Then you can find which line in your code raise this exception and check your query and column manually.

Comment: you can get these information from Exception but it is not my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Newer SQLite versions add the table names to the error message, but in neither case do you get the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your sql to sqlite browser, http://sqlitebrowser.org/ and attempt to replicate the error there and it should give you more information.