# Getting DATABASE file in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I am learning android an i have created a database with one table using SQLite.The problem is i want to view my database file to see if i am doing right or not.
I have searched on similar but solution i got was using emulator but i am using my device to run the app and i have no idea how i can get database file. Please any one who has got any solution.
**NOTE: i am using ANDROID STUDIO and device to run App, want to view my database on my laptop or pull the file on laptop/system memory.**
Thanks.

Comment: is your device rooted? if not, you're not going to be able to get the file. you can, of course, use the emulator and pull the file from there.

Comment: Here is a smiliar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997976/android-pulling-sqlite-database-android-device

Comment: No i have not rooted my device. Ok i will use emulator to view it Thanks @David M.

Comment: I was not Using emulator as it slows down my system.