# How to extract my Android (Lollipop) application's pre-populated SQLite database?

Tags: android, database

I would like to extract my Android database so I can examine it, but I cannot figure out how. I am aware of the two common methods (e.g., adb pull and copying to the SD card). I have successfully used the "copying to the SD card" method before, but neither one of those methods is working for me now.

I say "now" because I switched to a pre-populated database with this version of my application using **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database)** method.

When I use `adb shell` and `cd` to `/data/data/com.myapp/databases/`, this is what I see when I run `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwx--x    u0_a106    u0_a106    2017-07-19 11:03    cache
drwxrwx--x    u0_a106    u0_a106    2017-07-19 11:03    databases
lrwxrwxrwx    install    install    2017-07-19 11:03    lib -> /data/app-lib/com.myapp
drwxrwx--x    u0_a106    u0_a106    2017-07-19 11:03    shared_prefs
```

Notice that even though I am in the proper "databases" sub-directory, there is still another "databases" directory underneath that.

Now, when I execute this command:

```
run-as com.myapp ls -l databases
```

I see this:

```
-rw-rw----    u0_a106    u0_a106    21504    2017-07-19 15:53    MYDB
-rw-------    u0_a106    u0_a106     8720    2017-07-19 15:53    MYDB-journal
```

There is my database, in that (one level deeper) "databases" directory. I have tried using the `adb pull` command, but Android tells me `/data/data/com.myapplicaiton/databases/MYDB does not exist`.

So, I tried the next level, and still I get `/data/data/com.myapplicaiton/databases/databases/MYDB does not exist`.

Then I tried using the "copying to the SD card" method. I get a database, but it is 0 bytes in size.

Weird, because I can obviously see the database exists and it has a size larger than 0 bytes.

So ... what is going on, and how can I get my database?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

Per a request, I'm adding the code I use to extract the database:

```
adb shell run-as com.myapplication cat /data/data/com.myapplication/databases/MYDB > /mnt/ext_sdcard/MYDB.db
```

I also tried:

```
adb shell run-as com.myapplication cat /data/data/com.myapplication/databases/databases/MYDB > /mnt/ext_sdcard/MYDB.db
```

Then I use `adb pull /mnt/ext_sdcard/MYDB.db` to retrieve it from the tablet.

Comment: Can you show some code how you copy the database to that directory? I suspect that you unintentionally specified an extra `databases` folder in the path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Pulling SQlite database android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997976/android-pulling-sqlite-database-android-device)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added the code.

Comment: What happens when you do each of these?

Comment: Also, are you attempting to debug a problem with your app? If you are having difficulty opening the database in your app, the cause might be that the database file is not in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any file that resides in the `/data/data/package_name` folder of a debuggable app using the command

`adb exec-out run-as package_name cat remote_file > local_file`

In your case it will look like this

`adb exec-out run-as com.myapp cat databases/MYDB > target_file`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. All I get is a db file that has 0 bytes.

Comment: It gives you 0 bytes because it can't find the file. Check the path again. Methods [`getPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getPath()) and [`getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) will help you find it.